# monacaのカメラプラグインを用いた際、一定条件下で、端末アルバムに保存できない。

Tags: javascript, monaca, jquery, html5

大変お世話になります。

monacaのカメラプラグインで、

ーーーーーーーー
destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
saveToPhotoAlbum : true
ーーーーーーーー

というオプションを「同時に」設定したところ、ipadでは無事端末のアルバムに保存できますが、Android（ASUS Zenfone5）で確認したところ、アルバムに保存できません。

同様の問題が発生している方はいらっしゃるでしょうか。

私のZenfone5の問題なのか、他のandroid端末でも発生するのかが知りたいのですが、android端末を一つしか持っていないので、確認できない状況です。

知りたいのは、
１．同様の問題が発生している方がいるか。
２．ソースの書き方で回避すること（きちんとアルバムに保存すること）ができるかどうか。
です。

様々なソースで試しましたが、例えば、[https://ja.monaca.io/book/support/にある](https://ja.monaca.io/book/support/%E3%81%AB%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B)「画像変換機能付きカメラアプリ」で試しました。該当部分のソースを下記に記載します。index.htmlのscript部分です。
ご多忙のところ誠に恐縮ですが、よろしくお願い申し上げます。

```
    // 写真を撮影して保存する
    var getPictureFromCamera = function(onSuccess) {

        // デバイスのカメラアプリを利用して撮影し保存
        var options = {
            sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
            //  correctOrientation:true,
            //  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI 
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,

        };

        // カメラアプリを起動し、撮影して保存
        navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageURI) {
            onSuccess(imageURI);
        }, onFail, options);
    };

    function onFail() {
        console.log("写真を取得できませんでした")
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android端末にて同じ現象が発生しました。

monaca側に問い合わせたところ、
AndroidではDATA_URLの形式では端末内に保存することができないので
FILE_URIを使用してくださいとのことでした。